# How can I correct wrong interview date invitation politely?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I received phone interview invitation to 31st of November, which is not exist. How should I reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How should reply

Uhmm... December **has** a day number [31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December_31) (it is a Sunday this year, so not the best date for an interview though).

Anyways, if you need clarification I see no problem in just writing a regular email asking for such, something similar to:

> Greeting. On the last email it was indicated date X. Would you mind confirming that date for me please? Thank you.

---

*Edits per update*: So it seems it was actually November, and not December (got me wondering for a while, ha). Still if you want clarification you should ask for such as illustrated before. They should realize their mistake when you do so.

If they make the same mistake again, then it would be time to make the remark more evident, but still keeping it professional. Maybe something like:

> Greetings again. Thank you for confirming that to me.
>
> However, checking my calendar there seems to be no date X on November. Is there any other day that you are able and willing to take the interview? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry it should be November, just edit it and thnk u

Comment: @mojococo haha never mind :) expanded my answer a bit in case they insist on that impossible date. Good luck, glad I could help